# How to access metadata stored by Spark Streaming custom receiver?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Spark Streaming provides the ability to create a custom receiver, as detailed [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html). To store the data received by the receiver into Spark, the `store(data)` method needs to be used.

The data I am storing to Spark has certain properties that are associated with it. The [Spark Receiver class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/receiver/Receiver.html), extended by the custom receiver, provides several store methods of the form `store(data, metadata)`, that imply that metadata/properties can be stored with the data. The code extract below shows how I used this method to store the data and its metadata/properties.

```
public class CustomReceiver extends Receiver<String> {

    public CustomReceiver() {
        super(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    receive();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    restart("Error connecting: ", e);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        // Not needed as receive() method closes resources when stopped
    }

    private void receive() throws IOException {
        String str = getData();
        Map<String, String> metadata = getMetadata();
        Iterator<String> it = Arrays.asList(str.split("\n\r")).iterator();

        store(it, metadata);

        if (isStopped()) {
            closeConnections();
        }
    }
}
```

This stored data is accessed, from another class, as shown in the following code extract:

```
private void testCustomReceiver() {
    JavaDStream<String> custom = ssc.receiverStream(new CustomReceiver());

    JavaDStream<String> processedInput = custom.flatMap(row -> {
        return Arrays.asList(row.split("\\r?\\n"));
    });

    processedInput.print();
}
```

**Which now brings us to my question**: How can the metadata/properties stored with the data in the custom receiver be accessed from the `testCustomReceiver()` method shown above?

I have tried searching through the documentation and exploring the `JavaDStream` object in the debugger to search for the metadata, but to no avail. Any help or advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Aren't you already accessing the "metadata" by ```processedInput.print();```

Comment: @ab853 Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @yishaiz, probably not. This was a while ago, but if I found a solution, I would have added it on here.

Answer (score 1):

I've been digging around in the Spark code, and I've come to the belief that you can't ever access it again. In fact, I do not believe it is ever used.

The supervisor for your Receiver takes the metadataOption and drops it into a ReceivedBlockInfo (which is private to org.apache.spark.streaming). From there, it goes... nowhere. I can find no reference to ReceivedBlockInfo.metadataOption in the streaming codebase. It's hypothetically possible that ReceivedBlockInfo is serialized then deserialized into a different class, or some funky reflection retrieves the metadata, but both of those are such antipatterns that I wouldn't count on it happening.

Why is it there? I believe the intention was for it to be part of the [Metadata Checkpointing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing) system, but it either was never hooked up, or the connection between Receiver metadata and stream checkpointing was severed.

Either way, block metadata is gone once the block is dropped into the stream.